# Ethereum address length 32 bytes result (how to change it)

Tags: typescript, ethereum, web3js, method-signature

When trying to get the balance of an Ethereum address, I get the error:

***ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Private key must be 32 bytes in length.***

The line for the signature is:

```
var signed = await this.web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(rawData, this.wallet.privateKey.toString("Hex"));
```

And the var of the private key is

```
  var privateKey =  wallet.getPrivateKey();
```

I don't know what syntax to change, since an Ethereum account has 42 characters so I am so lost with this issue...

Can anyone help me?

I read some documentation about the versions of libraryis like [ether.js](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/utils/strings/), [signingKey](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/utils/signing-key/), [byte manipulaton](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/utils/bytes/) or [Strings](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/utils/strings/) on ethereum´s documentation.

If some one can help me with the correct syntax or something like this will be appreciated

Comment: Likely because some functions except `0x` string prefix, some don't , some expect binary as a argument. Generally, any hex/binary data handling in JavaScript is broken.

Comment: can you `console.log( this.wallet.privateKey.toString("Hex"))`

Comment: Thanks! @Mikko. @yilmaz I get this error in browser with console.log `Array(1)0: "0x988648bf30212548892cd2a3ffca5305e2b474b7"**length: 1**[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
vendor.js:154475 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Private key must be 32 bytes in length.`

Comment: I found this information but don`t the proper sintax, the article is [here](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-get-balance-of-an-ethereum-smart-contract-91ce4e7b4c4e)

Comment: It looks like you are passing an address where a private key is expected?